# XStream Custom converter

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I have this Xml:

```
<INDIVIDUO>
    <NOME>Some Name</NOME>
    <CPFCNPJ>xxx.xxx.xxx-xx</CPFCNPJ>
    <IMOVEIS>
        <MATRICULA>1511</MATRICULA>
        <MATRICULA>1512</MATRICULA>
        <MATRICULA>1680</MATRICULA>
        <MATRICULA>4698</MATRICULA>
    </IMOVEIS>
</INDIVIDUO>
```

And I have this Class:

```
publc Class Imoveis {
   String matricula;
}
```

So I wanna to convert that .... in a list of my class Imoveis.

****** UPDATE *****

this is my hole xml:

```
    <REGISTRO>
        <CANCELAMENTODEINDISPONIBILIDADE>3123123</CANCELAMENTODEINDISPONIBILIDADE>
        <CANCELAMENTO_TIPO>2</CANCELAMENTO_TIPO>
        <CANCELAMENTO_DATA>20/10/2016 18:44:58</CANCELAMENTO_DATA>
        <PROTOCOLOINDISPONIBILIDADE>31312313</PROTOCOLOINDISPONIBILIDADE>
        <DATAPEDIDO>02/07/2015 10:42:41</DATAPEDIDO>
        <NUMERODOPROCESSO>03720158260369</NUMERODOPROCESSO>
        <TELEFONE>11-11111111</TELEFONE>
        <NOMEINSTITUICAO>Nome da Instituicao</NOMEINSTITUICAO>
        <FORUMVARA>MONTE APRAZIVEL - CENTRAL -> 2 Oficio</FORUMVARA>
        <USUARIO>Usuario</USUARIO>
        <EMAIL>emaila@email.br</EMAIL>
        <CANCELAMENTO>
            <INDIVIDUO>
                <NOME>Nome de alguem</NOME>
                <CPFCNPJ>022.266.234-33</CPFCNPJ>
                <IMOVEIS>
                    <MATRICULA>1512</MATRICULA>
                    <MATRICULA>1680</MATRICULA>
                    <MATRICULA>1511</MATRICULA>
                    <MATRICULA>4698</MATRICULA>
                </IMOVEIS>
            </INDIVIDUO>
        </CANCELAMENTO>
    </REGISTRO>
```

So I wanna to save that structure in tables inside my Postgresql, and I having problem to transform the  tag in a list of my class (I have one table in my db to save (but each  should be an register in my db)
The tables, Registro, cancelamento and Individuo works fine. If the XML were like this:

```
<IMOVEIS>
  <MATRICULA>1511</MATRICULA>
</IMOVEIS>
<IMOVEIS>
  <MATRICULA>1512</MATRICULA>
</IMOVEIS>
<IMOVEIS>
  <MATRICULA>1680</MATRICULA>
</IMOVEIS>
<IMOVEIS>
  <MATRICULA>4698</MATRICULA>
</IMOVEIS>
```

but I can`t change the xml :/

Comment: What did you try so far? What's the error you're getting?

Comment: I will update my question:D